# How do I play video that can speed up, slow down, & play backwards?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I have the problem of needing to play a video while being able to arbitrarily increase or decrease the playback speed, as well as being able to have negative playback speeds (watching the video backwards). I don't know how to solve this problem. I've already tried VLC, but it doesn't support backwards playback, and forces you to increase & decrease the playback speed in steps (10% faster, or 10% slower). How do I do this?